# android startActivityFromChild - use of API

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to understand the [startActivityFromChild API](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java#3904).

The description says:

```
This is called when a child activity of this one calls 
its startActivity(android.content.Intent) 
or startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int) method.
```

I understand that child activity means an activity invoked by current (`parent`). The comment suggests that this API is called child when calls `startActivity()`, then why is the explanation write the parent (child activity of this)  ?

Can someone give an example on how to use this API ?

Answer (score 1):

The parent/child relationship between activities mentioned here is *not* actually the one between an activity and those it launches via `startActivity()`.

It refers to the parent of **embedded** activities, such as those inside a `TabActivity` (now deprecated), or an `ActivityGroup` in general -- although to be frank, I do not know of any other subclasses of `ActivityGroup`, so the "in general" may be unnecessary. :)

It's basically used to redirect some events to the parent. For example:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (mParent != null) {
        return mParent.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This implementation wouldn't make sense if the parent was the caller activity. However, in the case of tabs, you *do* want the parent activity to show the menu of its current (shown) tab.

There are quite a few `doXfromChild()` methods, and they're all related to this scenario (a child asking its parent activity to do something).

In short, the functionality related to these APIs is mostly deprecated since Fragments came out.

Comment: So this API is not useful anymore ?

Comment: Well, while deprecated, `TabActivity` is still a valid class. And there are some uses cases for `LocalActivityManager`. But they have mostly been superseded by fragments.